# SSRS with JDE query concatanate

Tags: reporting-services, casting, concatenation, jde

I have an SSRS report that is connecting to a JDE data source.
In the dataset for my query I am trying to concatanate three columns.
I tried the concat function, I tried two bars, I tried the plus sign, everything fails.
for example:
concat(col1, col2, col3) as "keylookup"
col1 || col2 || col3 as "keylookup"
col1 + col2 + col3 as "keylookup"

Is there a way that works for both SSRS and JDE?

Also is there a cast functiob or equivalent for JDE that SSRS supports?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are not able to concatenate within the query but when all else fails, you can use a Calculated field in your dataset to let SSRS concatenate the fields.

Create a Keylookup field with a value expression of:

```
=Fields!col1.Value & Fields!col2.Value & Fields!col3.Value
```

[image]

If your fields are not strings, convert them with CStr.

```
=CStr(Fields!col1.Value) & CStr(Fields!col2.Value) & CStr(Fields!col3.Value)
```

If your fields can have nulls, you may need to change them to blanks:

```
=CStr(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!col1.Value), "", Fields!col1.Value) & 
    CStr(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!col2.Value), "", Fields!col2.Value) & 
    CStr(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!col3.Value), "", Fields!col3.Value)
```

Comment: I found out what was causing issue with concat, it only accepts two arguments, and I was trying concat three arguments at one time, so I had to nest it. Also using the lookup function and concatenating was producing and error.